# Select a random item from an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I'm creating a bot in Shell Script:

```
# Array with expressions
expressions=("Ploink Poink" "I Need Oil" "Some Bytes are Missing!" "Poink Poink" "Piiiip Beeeep!!" "Hello" "Whoops! I'm out of memmory!")

# Seed random generator
RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)

# Loop loop loop loop loop loop ...
while [ 1 ]
do
    # Get random expression...
    selectedexpression=${expressions[$RANDOM % ${#RANDOM[*]}]}
    
    # Write to Shell
    echo $selectedexpression
    
    
    # Wait an half hour
    sleep 1 # It's one second for debugging, dear SOers
done
```

I want that it prints a random item from the `expressions` every second. I tried this but it does not work. It only prints the first one (Ploink Poink) every time. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The tags should be fixed -- there are no arrays in POSIX shell.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Change the line where you define `selectedexpression` to

```bash
selectedexpression=${expressions[ $RANDOM % ${#expressions[@]} ]}
```

You want your index into `expression` to be a random number from 0 to the length of the `expression` array.  This will do that.

Comment: Note that that code will still be biased towards the lower array indexes.

Comment: True.  However, unless your list of expressions is very long, the effect is minor.  $RANDOM is a number between 0 and 32767.  Say you had 100 items in your list.  The first 67 items would have a 328/32767 (.01001) chance, while the last 33 would have a 327/32767 (.00998) chance.  For a shorter list the difference would be even less.  Still, you make a good point, and the shell RANDOM function is not suitable for situations where you must have truly random numbers, such as cryptography.

Comment: For anyone that comes to this answer, and applies it in ZSH: Array index in ZSH starts at 1 (for some reason), so change the statement to: 
 
`selectedexpression=${expressions[$(($RANDOM % ${#expressions[@]} + 1 ))]}`

Comment: Thank you @loklaan, you are my saviour

Comment: To get a uniform distribution you can generate the random numbers by scaling a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0. Example for the array `a`: `echo "${a[$(awk '{srand($2); print int(rand()*$1)}' <<< "${#a[@]} $RANDOM")]}"`. Or use a program like `shuf -n1 -i0-...` or `jot -r 1 0 ...` which does the job for you.

Answer (score 30):

```
arr[0]="Ploink Poink"
arr[1]="I Need Oil"
arr[2]="Some Bytes are Missing!"
arr[3]="Poink Poink"
arr[4]="Piiiip Beeeep!!"
arr[5]="Hello"
arr[6]="Whoops! I'm out of memmory!"
rand=$[$RANDOM % ${#arr[@]}]
echo $(date)
echo ${arr[$rand]}
```

Comment: this gives - `Mon Mar 13 10:04:55 IST 2017
Whoops! I'm out of memmory!`

Comment: Additional items can be added to array, e.g. `arr[7]="Zip, ding, another line."`

Answer (score 6):

Solution using shuf:

```
expressions=("Ploink Poink" "I Need Oil" "Some Bytes are Missing!" "Poink Poink" "Piiiip Beeeep!!" "Hello" "Whoops! I'm out of memmory!")
selectedexpression=$(printf "%s\n" "${expressions[@]}" | shuf -n1)
echo $selectedexpression
```

Or probably better:

```
select_random() {
    printf "%s\0" "$@" | shuf -z -n1 | tr -d '\0'
}

expressions=("Ploink Poink" "I Need Oil" "Some Bytes are Missing!" "Poink Poink" "Piiiip Beeeep!!" "Hello" "Whoops! I'm out of memmory!")
selectedexpression=$(select_random "${expressions[@]}")
echo "$selectedexpression"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution that may be a bit more random than Jacob Mattison's solution (hard to say from the `jot` manpages):

```
declare -a expressions=('Ploink' 'I Need Oil' 'Some Bytes are Missing' 'Poink Poink' 'Piiiip Beeeep' 'Hello' 'Whoops I am out of memory')
index=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#expressions[@]} - 1)) )
selected_expression=${expressions[index]}
```

Comment: [This `jot` implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-162/jot/jot.c.auto.html) uses floating point calculations to generate the random number. The system's `random()` function is scaled down to a number between `0.0` and `1.0` which is then scaled up to the range given in the arguments, therefore I consider the distribution to be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

for **random**

1.

```
rand=("q" "w") 
r=$(shuf -i 0-${#rand[@]} -n 1)
echo ${rand[$r]}
```

2. 

```
echo `$((1 + $RAND % 5))` // **for number between 1..5**
```

Answer (score 0):

For use cases where a bit of python is OK so it becomes a one liner and readable, here is another take:

`echo $(python3 -c "import random;print(random.choice(['a','b','c']))")`