# Generate random number except values in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random

I want to generate a random nunmber between some values but except some values.

I have this:

```
shuf -i 1-9 -n 1
```

Or this:

```
$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
```

But i want to exclude the number 3 and the number 8, for example.

Comment: if generated 3 or 8, re-generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Practical General Solution

Instead of specifying a range of numbers you can specify each valid number individually using the `-e` option (at least for `shuf` from GNU coreutils) or you can specify the numbers in an (anonymous) file. Since the last option is more portable (works also for `shuffle` on BSD), we will use that. Now we only have to generate output with the numbers 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9. Here are some examples:

```
shuf -n 1 <(seq 9 | grep -Fxv -e{3,8})
```

```
shuf -n 1 <(printf %s\\n 1 2 4 5 6 7 9)
```

```
shuf -n 1 <(printf %s\\n 1 2 {4..7} 9)
```

```
shuf -n 1 <(seq 2; seq 4 7; echo 9)
```

#### Just For Fun

For each finite set S={i<sub>1</sub>,i<sub>2</sub>,…i<sub>n</sub>}⊂ℕ of integers you can come up (by hand) with a polynomial f such that f(x)=i<sub>x</sub> for all x∈{0,1,…,n-1}.

In general, polynomial f has degree n-1. Sometimes we can use rounding to reduce the degree. In your concrete case of S={1,2,4,5,6,7,9} we can use f(x) = floor(1.25x+1.5). Here is an implementation in `bash` using `bc` (the `(…) / 1` rounds down).

```
bc <<< "($RANDOM % 7 * 1.25 + 1.5) / 1"
```

A benefit of this method is that it works purley with built-ins if we scale all numbers inside the formula such that they become integers (here we scaled by a factor of 4).

```
echo $(( ($RANDOM % 7 * 5 + 6) / 4 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
until N=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 )); (( $N != 3 && $N != 8 )); do true; done; echo $N
```

One could argue that this way is imperfectly efficient, but in the absence of an obvious, simple alternative, it should suit.

Answer (score 1):

A function?

```
rnd() {
  local n=$(( $RANDOM % 10 ))
  while [[ $n =~ [038] ]]
  do n=$(( $RANDOM % 10 ))
  done
  echo $n
}
```

Then you can just say `x=$( rnd )`.

Comment: A loop would be far better than recursive function.

Comment: True. Will fix. Was just having fun between tasks at work, lol

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to select a random value from any set of values is to put the values in an array and select a random item from the array.  In this case:

```
values=(1 2 {4..7} 9)
random_value=${values[RANDOM % ${#values[*]}]}
```

Also see [Select a random item from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388488/4154375).

The code above has some limitations.  First, it doesn't work if the number of values to select from is greater than 32768, because the maximum value of `$RANDOM` is 32767.  (The size of the array could become a problem for numbers greater than that anyway.)  Second, the value returned by `RANDOM % ${#values[*]}` is (usually slightly) biased towards the lower array indices.  See [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/4154375) for more information.  If that matters to you, see the `rand` function in [BashFAQ/026 (How can I randomize/shuffle the order of lines in a file? ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026) for Bash code that generates unbiased (pseudo)random numbers in a restricted range.