# Random variable value from list

Tags: bash, random, random-seed

I'm trying to build a simple script which randomises data.
I will make it very simple.

Let's say I have the following data inside data.txt: `11 222 333 4444 55555`

So basically some numbers delimited by a space.
What I want is to add letters from `a` to `h` after each digit. Randomly selected from an array or from a file.

The problem is after executing the script, I get the same variable value after each letter.

Expected result: `1a1b 2f2a2e 3e3b3d 4a4g4h4c 5a5d5f5a5c`

What I get is: `1g1g g2g2g2g g3g3g3g g4g4g4g4g g5g5g5g5g5`

Script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
letters=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h")
random=$(shuf -i 1-9999 -n 1)
result=${letters[$random % ${#letters[@]}]}
result2=$(awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS="$result" $1)
echo $result2;
```

Comment: You need to loop around and generate a new random digit each time.  You are basically asking awk to print alternate characters separated by the single random letter you determined in the 3rd line.

Comment: I need to generate letters and insert them after each digit. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the loop. I'll read a bit

Comment: If you have `gawk` (check with `awk --version`), then write the whole thing in `awk`, it will be much more efficient. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Cliff-Random-Function for how to generate random numbers inside your script. AND, ++ for good (enough) first Q ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you need to use the `%` (modulo) operator to key into your list of chars that should be randomized. (As you seem to understand in your current code).

Comment: See [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/4154375) to [How to perform a for loop on each character in a string in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10551981/4154375). (It's by far the most upvoted answer.  Ignore the (poor) accepted answer.)  Bash has a built-in random number generator (`$RANDOM`), so you don't need to use an external tool (such as `shuf`).  See [Select a random item from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388488/4154375) to learn how to select a random letter from the `letters` array.  (The accepted, and most upvoted, answer is good.)

Comment: Didn't figure it out yet. I'm spending a lot of time for this script but I think this it's the beginner price. I hope I will get done this soon. Thanks guys. I can't accept an answer yet as I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Can't figure it out. Is there anybody who is able to do this for me? Thanks..